# Connect SQL Azure Database to SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: azure-sql-database

I try to connect my SQL Azure Database to the SQL Server Management Studio 2008. I Get a Connection to it but just with my Master Database of my SQL Azure Server. I want to see all tables of my second Database on the SQL Azure Server in the Object-Explorer of my SQL Server Management Studio.

When I try to switch the selected Database after I connected to the SQL Azure Server I get the following exception:

The access to the 'Databasename'-Database is not possible.

I have no idea why it throws this excpeption, google could not help me...

Comment: Are you using the latest SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 version of SSMS? That's what you need to manage SQL Azure. Or better yet, use SSMS 2012.  Also, when you connect, make sure to specify the database name in your connection window (you need to click on "Options >>" to see the Connection Properties tab, on which you can type your database name) .